GKE : Unable to see "logs" or "exec" in pod for autopilot private cluster
Cluster Architecture:

Private autopilot cluster with no external endpoint
For connecting to api-server, using jump-host, which only is a way to connect to cluster and run kubectl commands.
below is the attached details of cluster and service account.


service-account-details
Issue:
I have made a deployment of my application, but when I try to see logs or run "exec" command I get error saying :
[ Error from server: Get "https://10.250.82.36:10250/containerLogs/qa1/app1-5dd86f95dc-dmgjj/app1":
dial tcp 10.250.82.36:10250: i/o timeout ]
I am unable to understand what the issue is.
Earlier when i was trying to make deployment of one more service, I was getting same error, but after doing some R&D, I was able to resolve the issue by creating a serviceAccount and associate that to service-deployment. With this I was able to see logs or run "exec" command. This works once every few times and not for each invocation. The below screenshot shows more details about the installation and execution.

I have tried same solution for my main application deployment, but I am only able to see error messages. Below screenshot has more details about the error.

Let me know if any suggestions to exec or get logs for the pod.

Since you mentioned it is executing sometimes and getting errors frequently it's better to troubleshoot the kubelet logs and revisit the service account Role bindings to get some insight of what exactly happening. Check this other SO question for more information on how to check the kubelet logs.  If you have paid support try to create an issue. You can create a new public  Issue Tracker thread describing your issue.

Looks your jump-host is unable to communicate to the port 10250.
Make sure your jump-host has the necessary firewall rules for communication, and test this by using:
curl -v telnet://10.250.82.36:10250 

or
telnet 10.250.82.36 10250 

